# Discrete time process with discrete state space when initial condition fixed.

Tags: stochastic-processes, conditional-probability, discrete-time

Let $X_0\sim \mathcal{L}([0,1]^n)$ where $\mathcal{L}([0,1]^n)$ is some continuous distribution over $[0,1]$ and consider a finite set of doubly stochastic invertible $n\times n$ matrices $\mathcal{M}$. Define for $t\in\mathbb{N}$ the process $X_t = \Phi^t X_0$ where $\Phi\sim\mathrm{Unif}(\mathcal{M})$.
Conditional on $X_0 = y$ for some fixed $y\in[0,1]^n$ the process can only take discrete values since there are only finitely many matrices (argument would also work for countably many).

How do I interpret probabilities like $\mathbb{P}[X_t = z| X_0 =y]$? Since $X_0$ is a continuous RV the event $\{X_0 = y\}$ has no mass and hence conditioning on it seems wrong. Furthermore, by conditioning on the initial value the whole process becomes discrete while without conditioning it $X_t$ is a random linear transformation (invertible) of $X_0$ and hence also continuous. I am a bit confused how to deal with this role of $X_0$.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Probably the author is abusing notation for the density, or equivalently, starting the process at $X_0=y$ a.s. and evolve with the same rule.

Comment: But if I start a.s. in $X_0 = y$ can I transfer the results to the case $X_0\sim \mathcal{L}$ by the law of total probability for continuous RVs?